# Automatically scale normal layout-large to layout-xlarge

Tags: android, layout, scale

I created an Android app with a normal and a large layout.
The large layout would also look great on tablets (xlarge) if it could be scaled up to fit the screen.

Do I have to create the xlarge layout manually or is there any way to scale up the large by eg. 200%?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to create the layout manually. You can use the screen compatibility mode provided by android. Of course, the caveat being whether your application is suited for it.

See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html#Enable) page for more information about how to enable it.